# Route kubernetes out going traffic through openvpn server

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, acl, openvpn

I connect to atlas and use the Access Control List, to prevent unwanted connections. I have successfully implemented a VPN server with OPenVPN image, but i don't know how I can route my kubernetes outgoing traffic through my OPenVPN server.

Is there any setup I need on the cluster, docker or application side (nodejs).

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @lowercase00 no net yet.

Comment: it's weird that this is so difficult to information on. I've seen people saying to make a "border gateway" running OpenVPN and then use something like HAProxy to route the traffic from the pods to the border gateway, but I can't find a way to do that.